# Oracle: How to wrap a Cursor inside A Function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on an assignment and it requires me to place a cursor inside a function.
Now my cursor works fine, but I am having a hard time placing it inside a a function, how can I do this?

The function is supposed to have the same argument as the cursor.

Code:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_emp_salary (v_job_title VARCHAR2)
    IS
    SELECT employee_id, first_name, salary, min_salary FROM employees e JOIN jobs j ON
    e.job_id = j.job_id
    AND j.job_title = v_job_title;

    v_emp_id employees.employee_id%TYPE;
    v_emp_first_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
    v_emp_salary employees.salary%TYPE;
    v_min_salary jobs.min_salary%TYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN c_emp_salary('Shipping Clerk'); --I WANT THIS VALUE TO BE FROM A FUNCTION.

  LOOP
        FETCH c_emp_salary INTO v_emp_id, v_emp_first_name, v_emp_salary, v_min_salary;
        EXIT WHEN c_emp_salary%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID: ' || v_emp_id);
        dbms_output.put_line('Employee First Name: ' || v_emp_first_name);
        dbms_output.put_line('Employee Salary: ' || v_emp_salary);
        dbms_output.put_line('Job Min Salary: ' || v_min_salary);
        dbms_output.put('Result? ');
        IF v_emp_salary = v_min_salary THEN dbms_output.put('Yes');
        ELSE dbms_output.put('No');
        END IF;
        dbms_output.put_line(NULL);
        dbms_output.put_line('++++++++++++++++++++++++');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

**The assignment description**: *Write a function that takes job_title and checks all employees in
that job, if an employee has salary equal to min_salary print
“yes” else print “no”. Use a cursor*

Comment: You have not created a function. You have an anonymous PL/SQL block. What do you need help with? Are you just asking for a tutorial on how to create a function? Is it a stored function or a function within your PL/SQL block?

Comment: @MT0 What I want is how to transform this block into a function.

Answer (score 1):

The OP originally asked:

> I am having a hard time placing [the cursor] inside a a function, how can I do this?

and

> `OPEN c_emp_salary('Shipping Clerk'); --I WANT THIS VALUE TO BE FROM A FUNCTION.`

The code below solves the problem originally asked in the question; it is not intended to solve the assignment question that was edited in later as they are not one-and-the-same (that is left as an exercise to the OP).

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
  employee_id NUMBER,
  first_name  VARCHAR2(50),
  salary      NUMBER(10,2),
  job_id      NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE jobs (
  job_id     NUMBER,
  job_title  VARCHAR2(50),
  min_salary NUMBER(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO employees VALUES ( 1, 'Alice', 300, 1 );
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ( 1, 'Shipping Clerk', 200 );
```

**PL/SQL Block**:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_emp_id         employees.employee_id%TYPE;
  v_emp_first_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
  v_emp_salary     employees.salary%TYPE;
  v_min_salary     jobs.min_salary%TYPE;
  c_emp_cursor     SYS_REFCURSOR;

  FUNCTION get_cursor(
    v_job_title IN JOBS.JOB_TITLE%TYPE
  ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  IS
    c_emp_salary SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN c_emp_salary FOR
    SELECT employee_id,
           first_name,
           salary,
           min_salary
    FROM   employees e
           JOIN jobs j
           ON (   e.job_id = j.job_id
              AND j.job_title = v_job_title );

    RETURN c_emp_salary;
  END;
BEGIN
  c_emp_cursor := get_cursor('Shipping Clerk');

  LOOP
    FETCH c_emp_cursor INTO v_emp_id, v_emp_first_name, v_emp_salary, v_min_salary;
    EXIT WHEN c_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID: ' || v_emp_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee First Name: ' || v_emp_first_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee Salary: ' || v_emp_salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('Job Min Salary: ' || v_min_salary);
    dbms_output.put('Result? ');
    IF v_emp_salary = v_min_salary THEN dbms_output.put('Yes');
      ELSE dbms_output.put('No');
    END IF;
    dbms_output.put_line(NULL);
    dbms_output.put_line('++++++++++++++++++++++++');
  END LOOP;
END;  
/
```

**Output**:

> ```
> Employee ID: 1
> Employee First Name: Alice
> Employee Salary: 300
> Job Min Salary: 200
> Result? No
> ++++++++++++++++++++++++
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c3120de4d3ef464e0813e9b643253c7)*

Answer (score 0):

"Use a cursor" is pointless because every DML or SELECT statement is a cursor.

Anyway, I assume you are looking for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WRITE_SALARY(v_job_title IN VARCHAR2) AS
    CURSOR c_emp_salary IS
    SELECT employee_id, first_name, salary, min_salary 
    FROM employees e 
       JOIN jobs j ON e.job_id = j.job_id 
    WHERE j.job_title = v_job_title;

    v_emp_id employees.employee_id%TYPE;
    v_emp_first_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
    v_emp_salary employees.salary%TYPE;
    v_min_salary jobs.min_salary%TYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN c_emp_salary;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need something as:

(It needed substitute SCHEMA_NAME and FUNCTION_NAME)

(If return does not needed procedure can be used, and return statements should be removed)

(I don't run this example)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function SCHEMA_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME( v_job_title VARCHAR2) return number is

    CURSOR c_emp_salary 
    IS
    SELECT employee_id, first_name, salary, min_salary FROM employees e JOIN jobs j ON
    e.job_id = j.job_id
    AND j.job_title = v_job_title;

    v_emp_id employees.employee_id%TYPE;
    v_emp_first_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
    v_emp_salary employees.salary%TYPE;
    v_min_salary jobs.min_salary%TYPE;

    result number;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_emp_salary('Shipping Clerk'); --I WANT THIS VALUE TO BE FROM A FUNCTION.

  LOOP
        FETCH c_emp_salary INTO v_emp_id, v_emp_first_name, v_emp_salary, v_min_salary;
        EXIT WHEN c_emp_salary%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID: ' || v_emp_id);
        dbms_output.put_line('Employee First Name: ' || v_emp_first_name);
        dbms_output.put_line('Employee Salary: ' || v_emp_salary);
        dbms_output.put_line('Job Min Salary: ' || v_min_salary);
        dbms_output.put('Result? ');
        IF v_emp_salary = v_min_salary THEN 
             dbms_output.put('Yes');
             result := 1;
        ELSE dbms_output.put('No');
             result := 0;
        END IF;
        dbms_output.put_line(NULL);
        dbms_output.put_line('++++++++++++++++++++++++');
        return result;
  END LOOP;
END;
```